# Django Channels group_send buffers and sends all messages at once after receive concludes

Tags: django-channels

I am working with Django Channels (4.0.0) and have encountered an unexpected behaviour where messages sent in a loop with a delay are dispatched to clients all at once after the `receive` function finishes, instead of being sent one by one with the intended interval.

Here's a minimal example:

```py
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncWebsocketConsumer
import json
import asyncio

class ChatConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    room_name: str
    room_group_name: str

    async def connect(self):
        self.room_name = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['room_name']
        self.room_group_name = f'chat_{self.room_name}'

        await self.channel_layer.group_add(self.room_group_name, self.channel_name)
        await self.accept()

    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard(self.room_group_name, self.channel_name)

    async def receive(self, text_data=None, bytes_data=None):
        for i in range(0, 50):
            message = f'Message ({i})'
            await self.channel_layer.group_send(
                self.room_group_name,
                {
                    'type': 'chat.message',
                    'message': message
                }
            )
            await asyncio.sleep(0.1)

    async def chat_message(self, event):
        await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'message': event['message']
        }))
```

settings.py

```py
# Both layers have the issue.
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'channels.layers.InMemoryChannelLayer',
#       'BACKEND': 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer',
#       'CONFIG': {
#           'hosts': [(os.environ.get('REDIS_HOST', 'localhost'), os.environ.get('REDIS_PORT', '6379'))],
#       },
    },
}
```

asgi.py

```py
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
import os

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'my_app.settings')

django_asgi_app = get_asgi_application()

from django.urls import path
from core.consumers.chat_consumer import ChatConsumer

application = ProtocolTypeRouter(
    {
        'http': django_asgi_app,
        'websocket': URLRouter([
            path('ws/chat/<str:room_name>/', ChatConsumer.as_asgi()),
        ]),
    }
)
```

Expectation: The messages are received by the client with a 0.1-second delay between each.

Actual Behaviour: All messages are received simultaneously after a 5-second total delay, or in other words, when `receive` is completely finished.

Steps already taken:

1. Tried both `RedisChannelLayer` and `InMemoryChannelLayer`.
2. Tested with different WebSocket clients like Postman and Microsoft Edge.
3. Ensured no other middleware or additional layers are interfering.
4. Direct message sends (bypassing `group_send`) work as expected. These arrive in real-time.
5. Tried both `runserver` and using `daphne` directly.

Given the simple setup, it seems baffling that such behaviour occurs. Is this an inherent characteristic of how `group_send` operates, or is there something else that I'm missing?